# With GCC switch case ranges, is it possible to construct a single case that ranges [A-Za-z]?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, duplicates, switch-statement

Pretty straight forward question. 
GCC has Case ranges that allow for things like this:

```cpp
switch (c.toLatin1()) {
default: {
    foo();
    break;
} case 'A' ... 'Z': { 
    bar();
    break;
} case 'a' ... 'z': {
    bar();
    break;
}
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

The issue here however, is that `bar()` is redundant, and `'A' ... 'z'` will end up including a bunch of unwanted characters:

[image]

Conceptually, is something like the following possible?

```cpp
switch (c.toLatin1()) {
default: {
    foo();
    break;
} case 'A' ... 'Z' || 'a' ... 'z': { 
    bar();
    break;
}
```

Obviously that is pseudo-code, but you get the idea. 
Solutions if need be, can include text macros. I am more concerned with accidentally introducing bugs because I forget to add new code:

```cpp
switch (c.toLatin1()) {
default: {
    foo();
    break;
} case 'A' ... 'Z': { 
    foo(); // I add here
    bar();
    break;
} case 'a' ... 'z': {
    bar(); // but forget to add it here too.
    break;
}
```

Because those two cases, are effectively one case. 
Thanks.

Comment: Notice that `'A'-'Z'` is not guaranty to be contiguous, as for example with EBCDIC.

Comment: @Jarod42 don't you mean, `'A' ... 'Z'` ? Also, can you expand upon EBCDIC? If it is a platform thing, could I `#define` a text macro which would guarantee contiguous behavior?

Comment: Range A..Z in [EBCDIC](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code) contains éè.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Conceptually, is something like the following possible?

```
switch (c.toLatin1()) {
default: {
    foo();
    break;
} case 'A' ... 'Z' || 'a' ... 'z': { 
    bar();
    break;
}
```

Sure, just write:

```
switch (c.toLatin1()) {
default: {
    foo();
    break;
} case 'A' ... 'Z':
  case 'a' ... 'z': { 
    bar();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Addendum to this, I went ahead and defined a text macro: `#define case_Letter case 'a' ... 'z': case 'A' ... 'Z':` which works nicely.